# How can I make node.js run in a normal web hosting like GoDaddy

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, hosting

I don't know if this question is the most appropriate way to ask it. But I am really confused on how Node.JS works. I consider myself an advance JavaScript user/developer but I cant get a knack on how to implement Node.JS as a replacement for PHP.

I have been used to developing sites with PHP as it's backend. But now I want to change to Node.JS. Now I'm really confused when watching tutorials about node. I've seen that it always needs cli to be open, and when a user visits your site, do they need to enter port number into the URL in order for the node script to work?

Another question (if I hadn't already asked a million of them) is node.js considered safe if I use it as backend and put my Database details into the script? I'm just confused because if you enter the app.js path into the URL, the user can see all it's content not like PHP.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _"f you enter the app.js path into the URL, the user can see all it's content"_ - No, they can't, unless you've set your application up wrong. That file shouldn't be publicly accessible. You should also never hard code the credentials in your code anyway. You should use some config file (env variables or what ever) so you can have different configs on different environments and never store credentials in your VCS (like git). Regarding hosting for it, you need to find a hosting that supports node.js and follow their guides on how to deploy your app.

Comment: I would recommend doing some extensive research about how nodejs works. SO is the wrong place to ask this since it's a pretty extensive subject.

Comment: I guess goDaddy automatically sets up an Apache server that publishes your scripts to the clients. So no, you cant use nodejs in your current plan.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a NodeJS beginner and looking to host your app somewhere I recommend using [EvenNode](https://www.evennode.com/) or [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) to host your simple node applications until you have a better understanding on how NodeJS works.

Some docs on node hosting on these platforms

- EvenNode : [docs](https://www.evennode.com/docs/node)
- Heroku : [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction)

To answer your other questions :

> when a user visits your site, do they need to enter port number into the URL in order for the node script to work?

It depends on your setup. You can choose to run your node application server on a specific port or can always opt to run it on port 443 (https) or port 80 (http) and the client certainly wouldn't need to specify a port in the host name.

> is node.js considered safe if I use it as backend and put my Database details into the script?

Yes, NodeJS is safe. NodeJS is server side language just like Java, C#, Python, etc. It is safe so long as you don't expose any sensitive data, such as database connection information, publicly. The only reason you can view your app.js via (im assuming the browser) locally is because you are viewing it as a 'file://'. when this code is ran as a server, the server side code will not be viewable to the client.

Comment: Your answer is well understood! Thanks. But how about the "do I have to run CLI always when users use my site?" Thanks in advance

Comment: In order to run a node app, the machine which runs the app must be running a process for the node app. This is most commonly done by running a command in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You want a hosting with `root` access for Node.js.

So you want a `VPS` or `Dedicated Server` at GoDaddy.

The user does — not — have to enter the `port` always.

If you set it to `80` for `http` and `443` for `https` it works so.

You can have the main `script` in another directory.

Like that it is safe to enter `database` details.

The user cannot get the `script` then.